# Using Bean PropertyChangeListeners and psuedo-properties for event notifications

Tags: java, events, listener, javabeans

I know that properties are not necessarily related to any particular variable in the class. Would anything apart from perhaps seeming strange be wrong with doing this just so other classes can take advantage of PropertyChangeListeners, as in is there something going on behind the scene with beans that I'm missing? (The idea is that we want to hear when the file changes so we make a "fake property" that "is changed" when the file changes and the Listeners call methods to read the file accordingly.)

```
private PropertyChangeSupport pcs;

//Constructor omitted

public Object getMyProperty() {
    return null;
}

public void setMyProperty() {}

public void writeToAFile(String input) {
    //code omitted, writes the string input to some file.
    pcs.firePropertyChange("myProperty", null, null);
}
```

If anyone knows a better way that'd also be nice to know I suppose.

Comment: That sounds like a gross hack for the real problem. Even with a real observable/declarative-based system I do not know of a good justification of using a general property like this. If you really wish to pursue such a model, consider a `objectWriteCount` property - at least then the intent is known and there is a "bindable" value.

Comment: I may have just figured this out for myself. It'd probably be appropriate to just make a new type of Event and Listener. When I first started looking into this I was fairly new to Events and Listeners but now I see they aren't as complicated as they seem to that would probably be the best route.